# change Anchor link texts size and color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to detect an anchor link that is being clicked from the previous page.

I have a HTML like

**index.html**

```
<a href='test.html#project1'>project1</a><a href='test.html#project2'>project2</a><a href='test.html#project3'>project3</a>

bunch of stuff...
```

**test.html**

```
<a href='#project1'>project1</a><a href='#project2'>project2</a><a href='#project3'>project3</a>

<a id = 'project1'>bunch of stuff......</a>
bunch of stuff
<a id = 'project2'>bunch of stuff......</a>
bunch of stuff
<a id = 'project3'>bunch of stuff......</a>
bunch of stuff
```

I want to change the clicked link text color to red and bigger size. So when user clicks project1 from **index.html**, the project1 on **text.html** text will be red and larger.

Is there anyway to do this through CSS or jQuery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use this code:

```
if(window.location.hash){
    $('a[href="'+ window.location.hash +'"]').addClass('active');
}
```

and example CSS class:

```
a.active{
    color: red;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

This checks whether `window.location.hash` exists, if it does it searches for an `a` element with an `href` value equal to the hash. It then adds the `.active` class to any matched elements.